# pandas - fill in empty row values with other row values conditionally

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a table that looks like this (the ratio column was merged from another table based on the codename and date):

```
date         codename   ratio
2018-01-01   A          .5
2018-02-01   A          
2018-03-01   A          
2018-01-01   B          
2018-02-01   B
2018-01-01   C          .6
2018-02-01   C            
2018-03-01   C          .7
2018-04-01   C
```

I need to fill in the empty ratio values with **the most recent value given the codename**

Output should be:

```
date         codename   ratio
2018-01-01   A          .5
2018-02-01   A          .5
2018-03-01   A          .5
2018-01-01   B          
2018-02-01   B
2018-01-01   C          .6
2018-02-01   C          .6  
2018-03-01   C          .7
2018-04-01   C          .7
```

A got .5 because that's its only value. B remains empty because it has no ratio. C got .6 filled for February since that was the January value, but it's April value is .7 because that was the March value.

Comment: When you say the rows are "empty" what is actually in them? Are they nan, are they 0, are they empty strings?

Comment: They are nan but if it makes solving this question easier, you can assume it's 0/empty string/'null', because I can replace those values with anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to fill in `NaN` values, and its `method` argument allows you to fill forwards or backwards. In this case, we want to group by `codename` to ensure we don't fill across different names.

Assuming your dataframe is called `df`:

```
df['ratio'] = df.groupby('codename')['ratio'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Should do the trick. Printing `df` after this gets us:

```
         date codename  ratio
0  2018-01-01        A    0.5
1  2018-02-01        A    0.5
2  2018-03-01        A    0.5
3  2018-01-01        B    NaN
4  2018-02-01        B    NaN
5  2018-01-01        C    0.6
6  2018-02-01        C    0.6
7  2018-03-01        C    0.7
8  2018-04-01        C    0.7
```