# Efficiently filling df nan fields with values of other rows of corresponding attributes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df with incomplete data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 
                    'Group2': ['X', 'Y','X','X', 'Y','X', 'Y'],
                    'Fruit' : ['orange', 'banana', np.nan, np.nan, 'pear', 'apple' , np.nan], 
                    'Drink': [np.nan, 'soda', 'milk', np.nan, 'beer', 'beer', np.nan]})

  Drink   Fruit Group1 Group2
0   NaN  orange      A      X
2  milk     NaN      A      X
3   NaN     NaN      A      X
1  soda  banana      A      Y
5  beer   apple      B      X
4  beer    pear      B      Y
6   NaN     NaN      B      Y
```

I want to fill nans with values from rows of corresponding "Group" attributes, which [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006458/pandas-fill-in-empty-row-values-with-other-row-values-conditionally/52006660#52006660) explains how to do with `df = df.groupby(by=['Group1', 'Group2'], as_index=False).fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
  Drink   Fruit Group1 Group2
0   NaN  orange      A      X
2  milk  orange      A      X
3  milk  orange      A      X
1  soda  banana      A      Y
5  beer   apple      B      X
4  beer    pear      B      Y
6  beer    pear      B      Y
```

Perfect for this example but impractically slow for big dataframes (play with `size`):

```
size = 10000

bdf = pd.DataFrame({"Group1": np.random.random_integers(low=1, high= size/10, size=size),
                    "Group2": np.random.random_integers(low=1, high=5, size=size)})
for n in range(1,(int(size/200))):
    bdf[str(n)] = np.random.choice([1, 2, np.nan], size)

bdf.sort_values(by=['Group1', 'Group2'], inplace=True)
bdf = bdf.groupby(by=['Group1', 'Group2'], as_index=False).fillna(method='ffill')
```

How can we do this more efficiently with far bigger dfs?

Comment: what's the speed diff? over 200x? kindly share concrete values to give an idea of how impracticable the current solution is

Comment: How large is your data? The lower bound of the time taken is the time to read the input, and your algorithm appears to be asymptotically optimal already. Although you might want to look into bucket/counting/radix sort (it will be only a few times faster)

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I've since realized I was wrong and performance appears to scale linearly. Would it be good SO etiquette to delete this post?